# Как узнать скорость выполнения скриптов?

Tags: php

Возникла задача добавить язык R в php. Хотелось бы сравнить скорость выполнения скриптов на чистом php и  с использованием языка R. Как это можно проверить, с помощью каких ресурсов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для PHP
Первый способ (самый простой). Использую функцию microtime, время выводится в миллисекундах:

```
$start = microtime(true);
my_code();
$time = microtime(true) - $start;
echo 'Время выполнения скрипта: '.$time.' мс.';
```

Второй способ используя расширение [Xhprof](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.xhprof.php):

```
// start profiling
xhprof_enable();

// run program
my_code();

// stop profiler
$xhprof_data = xhprof_disable();

// display raw xhprof data for the profiler run
print_r($xhprof_data);
```